# Unifying a list of goals in prolog

Tags: prolog

I have a list of goals that I would like to be unified at runtime such that I get a list of Variable, value pairs. How might I do this?

Example

db.pl:

```
alpha(a).
bravo(b).
bravo(c).
gs([alpha(X), bravo(Y)]).
```

Interpreter:

```
?- [db].
?- gs(L), solve(L, Out).
L = [alpha(X), bravo(Y)].
Out = [[[X, a], [Y, b]], [[X, a], [Y, c]]]
```

Comment: I  do not see that this predicate makes much sense. First of all, there is no way to recover the name `X` and `Y` from the fact `gs/1`. Also, I cannot see what you are exactly after. I hope that this is not an exercise. Maybe you want to explain how you expect it to work?

Comment: I'm trying to build something akin to forward chaining in which I evaluate pre-conditions at runtime to determine which moves I can make. I need the variable pairs so I can define facts from the post-condition. For example if my precondition is `alpha(X)` and my post condition is `bravo(X)`. And `X` is unified with `a` I would like to define `bravo(a)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(I feel pretty bad for showing you this, I am very sure that you still misunderstood some point or another. In fact, it would be much better for you to study `setof/3` and `call/N`. But, well what do we do for earning rep...)

```
solve(L, Out) :-
   setof(Pairs, maplist(goal_pair,L,Pairs), Out).

goal_pair(G, [V,W]) :-
   arg(1, G, V),
   setof(V, G, Vs),
   member(W, Vs).
```

This will give you in SWI

```
?- gs(L), solve(L, Out).
   L = [alpha(_A),bravo(_B)], Out = [[[_A,a],[_B,b]],[[_A,a],[_B,c]]].
```

There is no way to recover the variable names directly. You would have to parse the program yourself.

Comment: Hehe got a good chuckle out of your first sentence, this is my first foray into logic programming and it must show. Its hard to find cogent advanced examples like this. Anyways this is exactly what I asked for so I'm marking it as the answer. But I'm wondering if it could be done for goals with an arbitrary number of variables? Right now it just solves the first argument in the term but doesn't work for terms with more than one argument (or repeated Variables).

Comment: @dropkick: Ultimately, what you probably want is some functionality like the toplevel, that shows you answer substitutions. However, you would have to define a lot to start this. [`term_variables/2`](http://www.complang.tuwien.ac.at/ulrich/iso-prolog/dtc2#term_variables) will come handy, as well as `copy_term/2`. In any case, these are are meta-predicates. Stick first to the pure, monotonic part of Prolog. There is a lot to learn there!